# Find Protocol Buffer (protobuf) buffer in file, not know where it starts

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a file that is suffixed by a protobuf buffer.
The problem is that I'm not sure exactly where the protobuf starts
Is there some magic prefix or something else at the beginning of the protobuf content that I can use to find it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard prefix for the start of a protobuf message. But most messages will always start with the tag number of the first field defined. For example field 1 with integer coding would be prefix of `0x08`.

You can also bruteforce it:

```
for (int length = MAX_LENGTH; length > 0; length--)
{
    if (try_decode(&data[datalen - length], length))
    {
        break; // Found longest valid message
    }
}
```

This would find the longest suffix (up to some maximum length) that can be successfully decoded. There is a risk that other random data may appear like a valid message.

You could also take advantage of the fact that [protobuf encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) is usually in increasing tag number order. So if you see a lower number after a higher number, you know the message boundary is there. But in common protobuf libraries this is difficult to check, as they don't expose the internal tag number order while decoding.